# Bootstrap modal contents from another page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make several modals in one page, and each modal should have different contents.

I know how to get the content from another HTML page, but the thing is I don't know how to import different contents from one HTML file.

So if there is a HTML file like this :

```html
<div id="one">
<h1>this is the first content.</h1>
</div>
<div id="two">
<h1>this is the second content.</h1>
</div>
<div id="three">
<h1>this is the third content.</h1>
</div>
```

I want the three modals to import each divs. So the first modal should have #one as its content, and the second modal should have #two as its content.

Comment: Try Bootbox JS. http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Post the code you've attempted to get the content from the other HTML page and explain what's not working